# Нужны ли еще запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Уже в следующем, 1995 году энергетикам Санкт-Петербурга была предложена новая уникальная разработка — графитовая фланцевая лента.

Answer (score 2):

Вторая запятая действительно не нужна, здесь пояснительные отношения, оформленные как однородные.

Answer (score 1):

Лишних запятых не нужно.